# Drupal 7: taxonomy sort by weight

Tags: drupal

I've created node type with CCK. Defined "weight" integer field. This node type, lets call it "Auto", is grouped by taxonomy terms. The question: how I can sort list of nodes by weight in Drupal 7. 
Ex.: Clicking on "GTR" shows cars sorted by weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by views module
http://drupal.org/project/views

Comment: I know that views used to create such pages. But can I use it for creating non static pages?

Comment: yes...you can use "views" to filter and display nodes by node content type or by node taxonomy terms...etc and its help you to sort nodes that filtered... you can sort by creation date or by field....sorry for my bad english...this will help you http://www.drupalove.com/drupal-video-categories/views